Lower bound on the size of generating sets of $C(X)$ as $C_b(X)$-module
In this answer I have shown that $C(X)$ is not countably generated as a $C_b(X)$-module when $X$ is not pseudocompact.
If $X$ is not pseudocompact, there exists a surjective ring homomorphism $T:C(X)\to C(\mathbb{N})$. Every such ring homomorphism maps $C_b(X)$ to $C_b(\mathbb{N})$ but this would also be obvious from definition of $T$, since this homomorphism is constructed from a subspace $\mathbb{N}\subseteq X$ (here I write somewhat informally, a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb{N}$ in $X$).
Therefore if $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is a generating set for $C(X)$ as a $C_b(X)$-module, then for every $f\in C(\mathbb{N})$ we can find $\tilde{f}\in C(X)$ with $T(\tilde{f}) = f$ and so $\tilde{f} = \sum g_if_i$ where $g_i\in C_b(X)$ so that $f = \sum T(g_i)T(f_i)$ and so $(T(f_i))_{i\in I}$ is a generating set for $C(\mathbb{N})$ as a $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module. Thus if $\kappa = \min\{|A| : A\subseteq C(\mathbb{N})\text{ generates }C(\mathbb{N}) \text{ as }C_b(\mathbb{N})\text{-module}\}$ then any generating set of $C(X)$ must be $\geq \kappa$ and from my post it follows that $\kappa\geq\aleph_1$.
What can be said about the cardinal $\kappa$? Is $\kappa = \mathfrak{c}$?

$\kappa$ is the minimal number of generators for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as a $\mathbb{R}_b^{\mathbb{N}}$-module, correct?

@Smiley1000 that's correct

I'll prove that $\kappa = \mathfrak{d}$ is the dominating number. Its know that all of the inequalities $\omega_1 = \mathfrak{d} < \mathfrak{c}, \omega_1 < \mathfrak{d} < \mathfrak{c}, \omega_1 < \mathfrak{d} = \mathfrak{c}$ are consistent with ZFC, so that this cardinal can't be simply described as $\omega_1$ or $\mathfrak{c}$. However, $\omega_1\leq \mathfrak{d}\leq \mathfrak{c}$ always holds.
I'll assume the convention $0\notin \mathbb{N}$.
Suppose that $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is a generating set for $C(\mathbb{N})$ as a $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module. Let $\tilde{f}_i(n) = \lceil |f_i(n)|\rceil + 1$ so that $f_i = g\cdot \tilde{f}_i$ where $g(n) = \frac{f_i(n)}{\lceil |f_i(n)|\rceil + 1}$. Clearly $|g|\leq 1$ so $g\in C_b(\mathbb{N})$, and so $(\tilde{f}_i)_{i\in I}$ is a generating set of $C(\mathbb{N})$ as $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module as well. So we can always assume that $f_i:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is any function, write $f = \sum_{k=1}^m g_kf_{i_k}$ where $g_k\in C_b(\mathbb{N})$. Its clear that we have $f \leq M\cdot (\sum_{k=1}^m f_{i_k})$ where $M\in\mathbb{N}$ is a common upper bound on $|g_k|$. Thus the functions of the form $M\cdot (\sum_{i\in I_0} f_i)$ where $M\in\mathbb{N}$ and $I_0\subseteq I$ is finite form a dominating subset of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. So there must be at least $\mathfrak{d}$ of them, that is $|I|\geq \mathfrak{d}$. Taking the minimum over all generating sets, we obtain $\kappa \geq \mathfrak{d}$.
Conversely, if $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is a dominating subset of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and $f\in C(\mathbb{N})$, then let $\tilde{f}(n) = \lceil |f(n)|\rceil + 1$ and $g(n) = \frac{f(n)}{\lceil |f(n)|\rceil + 1}$ so that again $f = g\cdot \tilde{f}$ with $g\in C_b(\mathbb{N})$ and $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ so that without loss of generality $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. Let $i\in I$ be such that $f(n)\leq f_i(n)$ for all except finitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $h = \frac{f}{f_i}$ is well-defined, bounded and $f = h\cdot f_i$. It follows that $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is a generating set of $C(\mathbb{N})$ as $C_b(\mathbb{N})$-module, so $|I|\geq \kappa$. Taking the minimum over all dominating sets, we obtain $\mathfrak{d} \geq \kappa$. Hence $\kappa = \mathfrak{d}$.
The proof is very simple and amounts to the observation that a function $f\in C(\mathbb{N})$ can be made into an integer function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. However I wanted to share it because it wasn't immediately obvious to me what cardinal is $\kappa$, and people who don't know what dominating cardinal is might still be interested in this question.
So if $X$ is not pseudocompact, then a generating set for $C(X)$ as $C_b(X)$-module must be of size at least $\mathfrak{d}$, and this lower bound cannot be improved on.

Awesome proof, sir.
